# ToastFactory crash in HUAWEI Devices

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I face crash in HUAWEI Devices with android version 6.0 & 6.0.1.
it looks the crash related to toast in HUAWEI Rom, this information I got from Crashlytics. 
even the crash is not in my app package, the crash comes totally from com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.ToastFactory
anyone has any idea how to resolve or overcome this issue? 
crash info:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class TextView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:558)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:434)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
       at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.ToastFactory.layoutInflate(ToastFactory.java:55)
       at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:271)
       at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:298)
       at android.widget.TextView.onTextContextMenuItem(TextView.java:9455)
       at android.widget.Editor$TextActionModeCallback.onActionItemClicked(Editor.java:3303)
       at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onActionItemClicked(PhoneWindow.java:3656)
       at com.android.internal.view.FloatingActionMode$3.onMenuItemSelected(FloatingActionMode.java:88)
       at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
       at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
       at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
       at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
       at com.android.internal.view.FloatingActionMode$4.onMenuItemClick(FloatingActionMode.java:114)
       at com.android.internal.widget.FloatingToolbar$FloatingToolbarMainPanel$1.onClick(FloatingToolbar.java:1045)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5264)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21297)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```